Is it possible to trigger all four of Khaj-Nisut's Sandglasses? Do they really do nothing?
Just got my speed party of Kaedehara Kazuha, Chiori, Amber and Cadance, and tried to activate all 4 of the Sandglasses at Khaj-Nisut.
According to the internet, it's not a puzzle, the sandglasses are just a way of getting the Four-Leaf Sigils, probably to avoid cluttering up the location.
But is it possible to activate all four within their 30 second timelimit, and if so, what would I need for it? Would I need Kaedehara Kazuha, Chiori, and a Venti wielding a fully refined The First Great Magic, and maybe Cadance or someone else to help if climbing is needed?
A.k.a 15% SPD boost from The First Great Magic, the double Anemo (Impetuous Winds) Elemental Resonance for another 10%, then Chiori's Swift Stride for another 10%, where Kaedehara Kazuha and Venti reduce the stamina cost of sprinting and gliding respectively.
